# HR start date changed multiple times

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, work-from-home

I started a new work from home position and the start date was supposed to be July 31, 2019 (my HR paperwork shows this date). The company sends you their own PC to use and my equipment is late. Is my HR paperwork a legally binding contract?

In other words...if it takes 5 more days for my equipment to get here do they have to pay me as of July 31st?

Comment: How much do you depend on their hardware? Is there anything productive you can do in the meantime e.g. read documentation or do paperwork they need? Have you asked them what they want you to do until it arrives? Have they said they won't pay you until you get the PC, or are you just nervous about that?

Comment: Are you hourly or salaried? If salaried, they likely have to pay you. If hourly, they don't except maybe so time for coordinating with HR.

Comment: Have you met anybody from this company in person? Be very careful! Several variations of "work from home" scams start this way. If they ask for a deposit for the computer, require you to buy special software, or send you a check to buy a computer from someone else because yours is late, run away! [Example on Money Stackexchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/60797/which-bank-is-responsible-if-a-fraudulent-check-is-spent-the-victims-the-scam)

Comment: Have you asked them what happens in this situation?

Comment: "Is my HR paperwork a legally binding contract?" What do you mean by that? Do you have a contract, or not? *You* should know that.

Answer (score 2):

Call your company's HR.  Let them know that the necessary equipment has not arrived and ask for the current status of the shipment.  While you are at it, you can ask them if you will still be paid ( you can also read your contract and employee handbook ).  Assuming this is a legit company and not some scam, they should be able to let you know the status of the equipment and give you all the details regarding your pay.

If they can't or won't answer those simple questions then you are likely the victim of a scam.  If this is the case, report them to the proper authorities and under no circumstances should you send them any money.